# What is the sum of this series: $\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Can anyone help me with this?

What is the sum of this series: 
$\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}$

I got it after plugging $x=-1$ in a Fourier series

Thank you!

Comment: $$\frac{2}{\pi}\left(1 - \frac13 + \frac15 - \frac17 + \ldots \right) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^1 (1 - t^2 + t^4 - t^6 + \ldots) dt\\ = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+t^2} dt = \frac{2}{\pi}\tan^{-1}1 = \frac12$$

Comment: You are probably supposed to use the original Fourier series to figure out the value of the sum! Are you familiar with Dirichlet's theorem?

Answer (score 7):

Substitute $u=k-1$. Then the sum becomes:

$$\sum_{u=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^u}{2u+1}$$

Which we can recognize as the [Leibniz formula for $\frac{\pi}{4}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80).

Thus your result is $$\frac{2}{\pi} \cdot \frac{\pi}{4} = \frac{1}{2}.$$

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 1}
{\pars{-1}^{k - 1} \over 2k - 1}}&
=\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-1}^{k - 1}\int_{0}^{1}
t^{2k - 2}\,\dd t
\\ & =
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}\pars{-t^{2}}^{k - 1}
\,\dd t =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over 1 -\pars{-t^{2}}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}{\dd t \over 1 + t^{2}} =
\color{#66f}{\large{\pi \over 2}}
\end{align}